# How can I disable multiple processes in IE8 (LCIE) without modifying the registry?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, registry

Is there a way to disable LCIE in IE8 without modifying the "TabProcGrowth" registry key?  I'm using an IE extension called "HTTPWatch" to benchmark the speed of a web application, but the multiple process feature is causing issues when I try to measure how long it takes for a pop-up window to load.

The reason I can't alter the registry is because several other people are doing the same exact thing, and my work does not feel comfortable asking other people to edit their registry keys.  In short, we don't want to be liable if they mess something up.

Any ideas on how I could temporarily disable this option without modifying the "TabProcGrowth" key?  Perhaps there is a command line way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to write a batch to call .reg file to enable and disable from time to time.